# Unable to delete last node in linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I trying to delete the last node from my singly-linked list. But I am still unable to resolve this error in code. My `deleteFromEnd` method is not removing the last node. After calling the delete method, it's still showing the node that I want to delete. The rest of the list is deleted, but the last node itself is not removed. Can you tell me what I am missing, or where the error is?

**LinkedList:**

```
package lab5;

public class LinkedList {

    public static void main(String argsp[]) {
        List ob = new List();

        ob.addAtStart("y", 6);
        ob.addAtStart("w", 4);
        ob.addAtStart("z", 3);

        ob.addAtEnd("a", 3);
        ob.addAtEnd("b", 4);
        ob.addAtEnd("c", 5);

        /*
         * ob.display(); System.out.println("Deleted first one");
         * ob.deleteFromStart();
         */
        ob.display();
        System.out.println("Deleted End one");
        ob.deleteFromEnd();
        ob.display();
    }
}
```

**List:**

```
package lab5;

public class List {

    Node head;

    public List() {
        head = null;
    }

    public List(Node e) {
        head = e;
    }

    Node oldfirst = null;
    Node lasthead = null;

    public void addAtStart(String name, int age) {
        Node newObject = new Node(name, age);
        newObject.next = head;

        if (oldfirst == null) {
            oldfirst = newObject;
        }
        head = newObject;
        lasthead = head;

    }

    public void display() {
        Node store = head;
        while (store != null) {
            store.display();
            store = store.next;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void addAtEnd(String name, int age) {
        Node atEndValue = new Node(name, age);
        oldfirst.next = atEndValue;
        oldfirst = atEndValue;
    }

    public void deleteFromStart() {
        if (head.next != null) {
            head = head.next;
        }
    }

    public void deleteFromEnd() {
        Node start = head;
        Node prev = null;
        while (head != null) {
            prev = head;
            head = head.next;
        }
        prev.next = null;
        head = prev;
    }

    public Node search(String name) {
        return head;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return (head.toString()).length();
    }
}
```

**Node:**

```
package lab5;

public class Node {

    String name;
    int age;
    Node next;

    public Node() {
        name = "Abc";
        age = 10;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        next = null;
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name + " Age: " + age);
    }
}
```

Comment: @nbrooks Now I asked new question.

Comment: What's the point of `head = head.next;`?

Comment: You're traversing using `head` instead of using your local variable `start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying head pointer of list which is wrong. Following method worked for me.

```
   public void deleteFromEnd() {
        Node start = head;
        Node prev = null;

        if(start == null || start.next == null)
        {
            head = null;
            return;
        }
        while (start.next != null) {
            prev = start;
            start = start.next;
        }
        prev.next = null;
    }
```

After analysing your code for little more, I found few other issues. You would need to update `addAtStart` and `addAtEnd` methods.

```
Node lasthead = null;

public void addAtStart(String name, int age) {
    Node newObject = new Node(name, age);
    newObject.next = head;
    if(head == null)
        lasthead = newObject;
    else if(head.next == null)
        lasthead = head;

    head = newObject;

}


public void addAtEnd(String name, int age) {
    Node atEndValue = new Node(name, age);
    lasthead.next = atEndValue;
    lasthead = atEndValue;
}
```

The reason being, suppose if I delete a single node from the end of the list. I would not be able to add an element to the end of the list.

Comment: thank you !  wow! Thanks man. Would you like to give me review my code is how much good and bad in just one comment I know this is not right time but please.

Comment: @BadarShahzadKhan You can post that as a new question here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @iNan NOTE: this code has problems with some corner cases i.e. there is only one element in list etc.

Comment: @VahanSimonyan Yes! You are right. After examining code I found few other issues here too.

Answer (score 1):

When you're deleting from the end of a singly-linked list you have to do things:

1. Traverse the list, and create a variable to refer to the *second-to-last* element of your list.
2. Set the node after the second-to-last node to be null

You should never change the value of `head` while traversing your linked list, because that effectively deletes the entire list. You have no way of finding your way back to the beginning since you've overwritten your `head` variable. Instead, iterate using a temporary variable which is initialized as `head`.

Finally, remember to consider the edge-cases where the list only has 1 element, or is already empty:

```
public void deleteFromEnd() {
    Node current = head;
    Node previous = null;

    while (current != null && current.next != null) {
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }

    if (current == head) {
        head = null;
    }

    if (previous != null) {
        previous.next = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @nbrooks

Answer (score 0):

Do not change head of Linked List, otherwise you will loose the list.
Try following modification of your function:

```
public void deleteFromEnd() {
        Node start = head;
        Node prev = null;
        if(start == null){
           return;
        }
        if (start.next == null){
           head = null;
           return;
        }
        while (start.next != null) {
            prev = start;
            start = start.next;
        }
        prev.next = null;
    }
```